# How to add all even numbers in an array (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to learn how to use reduce and don't understand why this isn't functioning correctly. Trying to add up all elements of an array that are even.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

array.reduce(0) do |result, value|
  result + value if value.even?
  result
end
```

Comment: You have a typo: `+` instead of `+=`.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments, **Doorknob** correctly identified that your specific example has a typo. You would need to use `result += value if value.even?`, not `result + value if value.even?`. Typically however, you want to avoid mutating state in functions like `reduce`, `select`, or `map`.

These functions are borrowed from Functional Programming languages, and they are usually written with pure expressions. You typically want to write the body of these functions so that they contain a simple expression that returns a new value.

If you're going to use `reduce`, you may want to consider pairing it with the `select` function and going for a simple chained expression.

```
array.select(&:even?).reduce(:+)
```

`select` filters the array using the given function. In this case, it will only pick values that are evenly divisible. `reduce` in this example is being passed a reference to the `+` function, by symbol, which will accumulate each of the values filtered array.

Both these functions can be written using blocks, which you may be more familiar with:

```
array.select { |value| value.even? }.reduce { |result, value| result + value }
```

Comment: I like your use of `select` here. It reads well and, as `select` returns an enumerator, I wouldn't think there would be an efficiency penalty over using `value.even?` within a `map` block.  A quibble: In your last paragraph I would just say something like, "The expression could also be written as follows", as you can't say one is "more explicit" than the other (not to mention that "explicit"--like `"true"--does not take an adjective :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

evens = array.reduce(0) do |result, value|
  p "#{result} #{value}"
  value % 2 == 0 ? result + value : result
end
p evens # => 12
```